# Why does the astrology sign for cancer seem to represent a yin and yang?

Tags: astrology, zodiac, iconography

So there appears to be an astrology tag with very few questions.  This somewhat represents mythology around cancer specifically.

[image]

Why does the astrology sign for cancer seem to represent a yin and yang?

According to [this](http://www.elore.com/Astrology/Study/cancer.htm)

> This is also seen as two crab's claws, intertwined in a way which
>   represents the dual nature of the Cancerian personality.  In this
>   form, it would be understood as similar to the Asian Yin and Yang
>   symbol.

Is this all there is to it?

Comment: This is a tough one b/c it requires running down the first appearances of the glyph, and analyzing the meaning in the context of the culture of the time.  There was certainly connection between ancient China and Europe per the silk roads and steppe hordes, but my *guess* is the yin/yang connection is modern.  (I'm also not convinced with what I've found so far online explaining the meaning of the glyph.  The hermetic literature may provide some insight on the meaning of the glyph, but I'd look for medieval sources as opposed to contemporary astrology.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the book "Divine Love Astrology: Revealing Spiritual Truth for Personal Transformation" it briefly mentions the following.

> The symbol for Cancer represents a crab's claws and also symbolizes
>   the yin and yang or the male and the female joined in the fertilized
>   egg.

Cancer I believe has often been viewed as very carrying so maybe this has to do with the opposing opposites of male vs female characteristics but I haven't found a source for this.